# Can I have Nautilus without Samba?

Tags: nautilus, samba, security

I have Nautilus installed, and Nautilus includes Samba.

I don't need the Samba options in Nautilus. There have been multiple vulnerabilities discovered in Samba, so I have to assume that there may be more vulnerabilities that are yet to be discovered.

Samaba is not actually running on my machine, so any risk must be low, but still, I would rather uninstall it totally, if there is a simple way to do so without impacting Nautilus.

Is there a simple way to have Nautilus, but not Samba?

Comment: Nautilus does not depend on samba.  Don't install samba and you don't have it.

Comment: The Nautilus "Samba options" probably come from the `smb` components of the `gvfs-backends` package, which `nautilus` recommends but doesn't depend on AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

apt-rdepends saith "yes, you can have Nautilus without samba. Even without tango. You want fries with it?":

```
$ apt-rdepends nautilus|grep -i samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Just to sure:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends --simulate nautilus
```

No samba there for me on Xenial 64. Try it for yourself. If there isn't a surprise, do it again without the "--simulate" if you want nautilus.

Steeldriver's comment re recommend vs. depend is totally to the point - 
the "--no-install-recommends" avoids stuff you don't have to have. Strictly speaking samba per se isn't even a recommend on my system - I just purged samba to test out of curiosity. But samba-dsdb-modules and samba-vfs-modules are. Still not depends though.

I'm not even sure why I had samba, because it didn't drag anything I remember ever using with it when I purged it. I guess I'll leave it off. Glad I dropped in to this thread.

Wait a second - I see you already HAVE Nautilus. Did you try:

```
sudo apt-get purge samba
```

or even

```
sudo apt-get purge samba*
```

?

That ought to do it without taking Nautilus. If it does take Nautilus, just re-install Nautilus with the --no-install-recommends as described above.